# Remove or reset Windows 10 password

Tags: windows-10, password-recovery, microsoft-account

I have forgotten my Windows 10 local account password. But I still have access to my PC, as I have set up a "pin". Now I want to change to an online account. How can I do that without knowing my local password?

EDIT- creating new account and deleting previous one works but is there a way I can transfer all my settings to new account before deleting the existing account so both accounts are exactly the same?

Comment: [Similar question asked here](http://superuser.com/questions/951907/locked-out-of-windows-10-login-no-longer-shows-administrator-but-only-an-accou), answer  by TD.512 should work for your situation. It will solve the local account password issue, then you can do what you need.

Comment: @Moab Will this solution lead to any loss of data or settings for the user account?

Comment: It should not if you follow the instructions carefully on what to copy from the old users folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually a hack:

1. Boot into recovery mode (possibly on a windows install disk).
2. Open the Command Prompt.
3. Execute this:

   `copy c:\windows\system32\sethc.exe c:\`

   `copy /y c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe c:\windows\system32\sethc.exe`
4. Boot into normal windows install.
5. Press the shift key 5 times rapidly on the login screen.
6. Stare at the administrator cmd that appeared and execute this:

   `net user`{your username here}`*`
7. Enter new password, press enter and confirm new password.
8. Login with new password.
9. Copy `sethc.exe` in `c:/` to your `c:/windows/system32`, replacing the existing `sethc.exe`. **Not doing this allows anyone to summon the cmd on the logon screen**.
10. Remember your password.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

Delete the older local account completely and make a new user, and then access to the online account by using the new user password that you had created recently.

Check these links:

1) http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5464-user-account-delete-windows-10-a.html

2) http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5239-password-user-account-change-windows-10-a.html

Comment: And how will this affect my installed programs, data and settings?

Comment: Yeah it will affect your PC setting, if you are using software in which you had include that account details than it might it will affect that software. Like SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to switch from local account to Microsoft account, the system will still require you to enter the password for your local account (not PIN). If you've forgotten it, you can remove it with the freeware [Offline NT Password & Registry Editor](http://www.chntpw.com/download/).

Answer (score 0):

As you said you can login to your PC with PIN.
Then you can reset your account password or remove it with Computer Management. Once you have set a new password you can switch to a Microsoft account easily.

Log in to your Windows 10 PC with your PIN.

and Follow the steps in this tutorial to [reset your account password in Windows 10 with PIN](http://www.craxworld.com/reset-windows-10-account-password-10297/#m2).

I have tested it. Works great without any problem.

Comment: Computer Management has no 'Local Users And Groups' option. Although I solved the problem by resetting password by 'net user' command.

Comment: It's impossible. You should have look at left side. It is always there in all editions of Windows.

Comment: It's not. https://postimg.org/image/t805h0d3l/

Comment: @Shyam 'local users and groups' is removed from home or basic editions of windows for windows 10 and maybe windows 8 (i am not sure about 8). Upgrading to pro, ultimate, or enterprise 'unlocks' these snap-ins. There is no workaround

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there are two different methods to reset or remove password for a local windows account. One is to edit the registry entry by booting into safe mode. The representative of this kind is  NTPasswd]. The other method is brute-force the password with rainbow table. and **Ophcrack** is the best tool for that.

The above two is designed for advanced users because it is a bit tricky. That is why paid programs come in and preferred by normal users. One big advantage is intuitive graphics interface. You only need a clicks to reset the password (for example). Here is a demo on how to [reset windows 10 password](http://www.uukeys.com/reset-windows-10-password.html).

There are a bunch of tools for password reset. Just choose the right one according to your own situation.

Answer (score -1):

You can go to the Microsoft site and rest your mail password, then you must go to start menu-->settings-->accounts-->your account. then you should authorize your account then you can sign into your windows with your mail password.

here is the link:

https://account.live.com/ResetPassword.aspx?wreply=https://login.live.com/login.srf%3fwa%3dwsignin1.0%26rpsnv%3d12%26ct%3d1443874617%26rver%3d6.5.6509.0%26wp%3dMBI%26wreply%3dhttps:%252F%252Fwww.microsoft.com%252Fen-us%252F%26lc%3d1033%26id%3d74335%26bk%3d1443874670&id=74335&uiflavor=web&uaid=36de42274282411f8a8b7ddcada0bc22&mkt=EN-US&lc=1033&bk=1443874670

Comment: But this is to reset my online account password. I remember that, I have forgotten my local account password.

Comment: Also, it seems very unlikely that that link will work for any length of time.