# Windows 10 upgrade OK but asks for password

Tags: password-recovery

I have allowed my laptop to upgrade to windows 10 using the automatic unattended method, When I returned to the machine it seemed to be finished Ok but it immediatly asked me for a password in the user name it had given me. as it was unattended i obviously never st a password. In addition its is also telling me that administrator has been disabled and that I should see the system administrator. Has anyone come across this before? Machine currently unuseable as I cant log in.

Comment: Try logging in with a blank password just in case it's asking for one but none was entered in during the unattended process.

Comment: [So enabled the Administrator account?](http://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221) then that account to change the password.

Comment: You can get into safe mode, and use the net user command to remove the password against your username.