# Install LibreOffice for Single User Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation

I have a Surface 3 with Windows 10.  I do not have the administrative password.  I tried to install LibreOffice 5 but the install fails after asking for admin privileges.

When I installed Chrome, it also failed, but then told me I could just install for the currently-logged-in user without the admin password; which it did and is working fine.

Is there a way to ask or force LibreOffice to do this same type of install?

Alternatively, is there a way to run LibreOffice on Windows without installing at all?

I'm not asking how to recover an administrative account, this is a company computer and it maintains admin privilege.

Additional Steps:
I found a similar question at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/13191/use-on-windows-without-installing/ where the LO staff suggests extracting the msi and then running the apps, but this doesn't work for me.  I am getting a missing dll - MSVCR120.dll.

Comment: you can use a portable version of libre office that will work only for the current user, http://portableapps.com/apps/office/libreoffice_portable

Comment: Enable the built-in Administrator, install with user, disable built-in Administrator. If you don't know how, check my answer, on how to do exactly that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](http://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer)

Comment: " am getting a missing dll - MSVCR120.dll." - So install the required dependency, Visual C++ 2013, which can be found on Microsoft's website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do an installation without administrator privileges, but you could use what's called a [portable application](http://searchcloudapplications.techtarget.com/definition/portable-app-portable-application), meaning it doesn't have to install, it is completely self-contained and can be copied from computer to computer easily. Libreoffice is available as a portable application [here](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/libreoffice_portable)

Comment: Do you know what was differences allowed me to succeed installing chrome and dropbox?

Comment: @nexus_2006 If you are asking my Chrome and Dropbox could be installed without administrator privileges? Obviously nothing in their installation scripts required administrator access (this is different than UAC that prompts you all the time if its OK) but something in LibreOffice does.

Comment: Those apps both tried to install something that wanted admin rights, but when I was unable to provide it they failed more gracefully I guess