# Resetting Admin Password Over USB For M.2 SSD

Tags: passwords, administrator, reset

I have a laptop with windows 10, and the administrator password forgotten and the bios password forgotten. I don't want to reformat the M.2 SSD, so i take it out, put it in my M.2 SSD to USB adapter. I decide to boot it up in another computer, but the same problem occurrs, i cant log in to administrator account. How can i reset the password on the Administrator account on the SSD? I have full access to my desktop computer, have windows 10 and kali linux. I am just a computer user so please give detailed step by step instructions please.
Thanks!

Comment: I have an answer that explains in detail how to do this.

Comment: @Ramhound That's nice. Can you provide a link for the OP please? :)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221

Comment: My laptop is virtually bricked! Is there any way i can hash it from a different operating system?