# Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, gpedit

I locked out myself by adding something in **"Run only specified windows application"** in `gpedit.msc`. I am running windows 7 Enterprise 64bit. I am logged in as administrator but can't run anything including `cmd.exe`, `mmc.exe`, `gpedit.msc`, or `regedit.exe`.

I can't manage my user accounts.

Comment: You will have to boot to WinRE, load the registry Hive, and manually make the change to the registry.

Comment: How do I do that? I have never done anything like this before, could you please give me steps on how to accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: You can either create your own WinRE image or use the one that is contained on the Windows 7 installation disk.  Once you do that you can use any number of tutortials on [how to enable the Administrator account from within WinRE](http://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221), in order to get an idea how to load the Hive, from within the WinRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's (only) a User-level setting (HKey Current User). If you edit it for just your user (via local polices) then you may be able to simply log in as a different administrator account and undo it for the related user hive (via the registry).

If you're doing it by editing the registry, that GP controls the `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` registry key.

If that doesn't work, then another option is to log into another computer on the network, and then use either GPEdit.msc or Regedit to remotely undo the restriction list you implemented.

To run GPEdit.msc against a remote computer, you have to run it form the command-line as such:

`gpedit.msc /gpcomputer: Computername`

Comment: Appreciate you taking time to help me, however I could not use your suggestions. The laptop has only one Admin account, no other accounts. And now when I try to create new account, it gives the action canceled error due to lockout. It wont run the regedit.exe. The laptop is not on network, it is a stand alone machine so can't use remote option either.

Comment: Probably time to restore/reinstall..

Comment: Oh noooooo ... I was hoping you won't say that !!!

Comment: The solution by Techie007 actually worked. I took a shot it and plugged it into my office network. I was able to access the gpedit.msc of locked computer thru another computer on the netwrok, I fixed the error in gpedit.msc and after reboot I gained the full access of computer. Two thumbs up for Techie007.