# How can I retrieve data from Windows 10 HDD, when I get this gparted error?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, gparted

I have a laptop with windows 10 on an HDD.  Windows 10 boots fine, but the user kept trying to login, and it won't let them.  They seemed certain that they were typing in the correct password (I mean...who knows).  They were getting a new laptop,and just needed their old stuff of the old laptop, so I just pulled out my handy Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop live usb.  Here's the steps I've taken so far.

When I used `df -h` the output didn't show the disk....which was weird, since it would boot into the drive fine.

I then tried using `gparted`.  When the file systems show up, it's showing the drive, and the partitions, but the partition with the data on it has the following error.

```
**Warning:**
Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for ntfs file system support:  ntfs-3g / ntfsprogs.
```

I have checked, and I have the most recent version of `ntfs-3g`.  I didn't see anything for `ntfsprogs`.

I double checked that the Windows 10 drive was actually booting, and it is.

What else could I try to get the data off of this partition?

Comment: Just enable the built-in Administrator account.  Check my answer on how to do that for more information.

Comment: [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](http://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221)

Comment: You might want to try a recent Ubuntu version (like 16.10) for better compatibility.

Comment: Ramhound's solution worked for me.  It doesn't answer the specific question asked, but it did fix my issue.

Answer (score -1):

It could be that the disk / partition is encrypted.  In that case you would need to decrypt the drive before you could read it.

If they used bitlocker to encrypt the drive you can try using the command "manage-bde -status" to check if it has bitlocker encryption.

If it does turn out to be encrypted I am not aware of a way to overcome that.