# Administrator password not working after net use command

Tags: net-use

I tried to activate the hidden Administrator in Windows 10 Professional by issuing

```
net use administrator active=yes
```

but the administrator was already active and had a password thats not working anymore. Can someone please explain me about that problem and (hopefully) how to solve it in an easy way? i hope i gave enough information. thanks a lot.

Comment: [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](http://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221)

Comment: Thank you but i think thats not my case. the user account is active, only the password isnt correct!

Comment: You can use your current account, which is an Administrator since that command work, to change the password of the Administrator user.

Comment: i cant because the password wont work anymore! if i want to do admin stuff i always had to insert the passwort for Administrator and that now wont work anymore! i have a user "root" and the user "administrator" (activated long time ago and gave him a password).

Comment: [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](//superuser.com/q/72244)

Comment: The command you issued, to enable the Administrator account, requires elevated permissions. So I am suggesting you use the account,you issued the command with, to change the password of the Administrator account.