# Password Hacking How to get into admin account?

Tags: permissions, passwords, cmd.exe, user-accounts, administrator

I need some help getting into my dad's admin account on my laptop.  I need to know the password because my dad forgot it.

I need to be able to do this without Command Prompt, because my dad blocked it.  Any methods that don't require admin permisson would be helpful.

Thanks :)

Comment: Is his account the only one on the computer?

Comment: No it has mine and his account.

Comment: You would have to brute force the password and/or forcefully change the password to the account outside of Windows.  There are numerous tools that will do that.  An easier way is to enable the built-in Administrator account from within WinRE and change the existing account's password, from within Windows.  There are numerous tutorials on how to enable the built-in Administrator account.  I even wrote a detail answer on this very site on how to do that.

Comment: "my dad blocked cmd " and "my dad forgot the password"  ... seems fishy

Comment: @JourneymanGeek that smelly smell...

Comment: Why does that seem fishy??

Comment: This question is a little suspect, although providing the OS would help.

Comment: The OS is windows 7

Comment: @Ghostdog12 - It sounds like you are trying to access your father's account with their permission.  Questions that seek to forcefully get around parenteral and corporate control are out of scope for Superuser.  I provided you two good solutions, neither, are new problems we have not answered in the past.  The account's password cannot be brute forced from within Windows, you need to either change the account forcefully using a specialized tool, or enable the built-in Administrator account.

Comment: I'm trying to get into his account as he does not live in our house anymore and I'm not allowed to see him.

Comment: [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221).  At the step it indicates to download a Windows 10 ISO, download a Windows 7 ISO instead, the procedure is identical other then that.

Comment: @Ghostdog12 Look into Kali. It is a Linux OS specific for this task

Comment: I would suggest this as a duplicate: [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

Comment: Sorry I got told to come here by people on Stock Overflow and I forgot to look on here sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I go ahead with an answer I'm not responsible for these actions. Since it requires to remove the password and gaining access to restricted information on the admin account. So if you get beat up by your "dad"...not my problem. But this answer could be useful to pc techs that deals with lost password on any account in Windows.

Theres a small app that I use all the time and its Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor[Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/bootdisk.html)

This allows you to remove the password in the sam database on your windows installation. First you'll have to download that file and burn it on a cd or usb. If you have questions regarding burning then the instructions are on that website as well.

Boot the computer with that usb or cd you just made and after a couple of moments and lots of text (yes, its in text, no graphics or gui...just text).

Theres a [walkthrough](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/walkthrough.html) in that website but its pretty basic. here are the steps

1. first you'll have to select the disk so type the number beside on the left and press ENTER
2. second you'll need to select your path and registry file. Most of the time, you just have to press enter
3. at this point you have to select 1 for password reset which most people use anyway.
4. then you'll have to press 1 and ENTER for editing users & passwords
5. Now when you'll see the table, just type in 0x%%%%. Replace the %%%% with the RID on the left side of the username. For example, if you see 3f08 beside the username `dad` then you will need to type 0x3f08 and press ENTER (note: admin is always 01f4)
6. then type 1 and ENTER to Clear the user password
7. finally just type ! (exclamation point) and type Y to write changes to file and just reboot your computer.

AT this point the account you just reset will be blank so you'll be able to enter the account flawlessly. But again, I'm not responsible for any actions since this application used in the wrong hands can be devastating.

Comment: Problem for this to work in need cmd.exe and I went round a mate house and tried it and i could not get cmd.exe to install the bootloader. If you can help me, can you please so me how to write the code in. Also when I try to install the bootloader it says "Accessing physical drive: Access is denied. Did not successfully update the MBR; continuing...

Answer (score 2):

You can **remove** any password on windows via Linux Live USB-Stick. However, this intrusion will be detected, as the password is removed, not just read.

This will fulfill the request of providing access to your fathers computer, but it can not be concealed.

**Edit**

#### How to

1. Get a bootable linux medium. It does not matter which, as long as it fits your hardware. It must be Ubuntu based (tested with Ubuntu)
2. Boot your computer with said boot medium
3. Install the package `chntpw` (e.g. with `sudo apt-get install chntpw`)
4. Mount your HDD (over the graphical interface or via terminal)
5. `cd` into `/media/<your harddrive name here>/WINDOWS/system32/config/`
6. Run `sudo chntpw SAM` (SAM is the name of the file which holds the registry)
7. Follow the onscreen instructions

Written freely after https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14369/change-or-reset-windows-password-from-a-ubuntu-live-cd/

### Disclaimer

This may break your computer, no success gurantee yada yada.... Do anything on your own risk.

Comment: Oh great, someone removed the complete comment history without further notice. -.-