# How to disable/remove administrator account in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, administrator

I'm using windows 10 home version. I somehow accidentally enabled the administrator account when trying to fix another account and couldn't seem to remove it. It keeps showing up in the login screen, which is quite annoying, and I wasn't able to remove it using the command `net user administrator /active:no`. Also, I noticed that the account showed up in the `netplwiz` window (it wasn't there before), but I couldn't delete it from there either.

[image]

**Update**:

I just found out that, interestingly, **two** administrator accounts started showing up in the login screen. One would require only the password, and the other one would require both the username and the password to login. Any ideas why this is happening?

I was just thinking, but...could this possibly suggest that I had another user account actually named "Administrator"? (the `netplwiz` window is only showing one administrator account)

The two accounts showed up like this in the login screen.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you take a screen shot or a photo of this screen and attach it to your question that shows two administrators? Check the `Computer Management` > `Local Users and Group` > `Users` if applicable on your Windows 10 version and send a screen shot of the two named "administrator" accounts from there as well. Otherwise, update the `netplwiz` screen shot to show the two from that window.

Comment: You can always use [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221) answer to disable the built-in Administrator account.  As for the possibility have having multiple accounts named Administrator, only you can tell us if that is the case, you have not provided us enough information to determine if that is actually the case or not.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot delete the built-in administrator account, but you can disable it.

Run a Command Prompt (cmd) with "Run as Administrator" and enter:

```
net user administrator /active:no
```

Comment: Um...I already tried this method, but it didn't work. I also updated some details which might be related to the problem.

Comment: A second admin account would show up in Computer Management / Local Users and Groups, or in Control Panel / User Accounts / Manage another account.

Comment: There are two accounts in the control panel, my user account and one administrator account which wasn't there before. (I'm using home version, so there isn't a "Local Users and Group")

Comment: You may try to disable the built-on admin (`/active:no`) and delete the other one (link : [How to Delete a User Account in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5464-delete-user-account-windows-10-a.html)), if you are sure it was never used.