# How can I log in to my hidden Windows user account?

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-registry

I was able to hide my account through regedit. The account I hid is my only admin account. I left a standard account open but I can't log back in to my account now. Everything I have tried isn't working because I don't have the permissions to make changes.

I have Windows 8.

Comment: Enable the built-in Administrator account and unhide your account

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer) instead of Windows 10 ISO download a Windows 8.1 ISO

Comment: The proposed duplicate asks about a *disabled* account, whereas this question is asking about an account that's been *hidden* through the registry.

Comment: @Twisty My suggestion is to use the built-in Administrator account and reverse the registry modification.  Reason for the duplicate flag, "I don't have the permissions to make changes.", which the built-in Administrator would have

Answer (score 1):

1. Logon with your standard user account
2. From Start, search for `regedit.exe`, then Shift+right-click it and choose **Run as different user**
3. Enter your Administrative account credentials
4. Reverse the changes in the Registry that hid your account
5. Logout so the changes can take effect