# Locked out from WIN10 as an old user

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, login-screen

I configured an old laptop for a new employee. I changed computer name to `SURNAME-FIRSTNAME` and with the `netplwiz` I changed the user name to Surname Firstname.

After that I restarted the computer, but in login screen there is the old user name shown and no button to switch user. It says that the password is wrong, too.

I'm I totally locked out from the computer or is there some tricks that I can do? Do I need to do the recovery or can this be fixed by another way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "is there some tricks that I can do?" - Enable the built-in Administrator and verify the username and then reset the password.  [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221)

Answer (score -1):

I would give this a try (working by memory on Windows XP era old bits of brain-information, sorry):
On the login screen, where it shows your old username, hit Ctrl+Alt+Del TWICE, I think that will show the option to type an username!

**Else** I would try kon-boot, there are some versions on the net: You can boot your computer with a kon-boot prepared pendrive, run kon-boot, and then (without restarting) let Windows boot normally. If you are lucky, you will be able to bypass the password for this session!
Good luck

Comment: Sorry, but why a negative point? I am new to posting on SU, so I would like to know the reason to improve my answers. Thank you!