# What happened to administrator account in Server 2016 Essentials

Tags: administrator, windows-server-2016

I recently installed my first copy of Windows Server Essentials 2016.
An odd thing happened. I walked through the setup and it had me create and administrator password. Then, it had me create another user with admin privileges. Then, the "administrator" account disappeared. I can't log in as administrator anymore. It doesn't show up in the dashboard.
Is this normal behavior or did I do something wrong? Can I get it back?
I have added several user accounts and they are work fine.

Comment: Run the Active Directory Users and Computer snap-in, then look in the Users container. Do you see the Administrator account? Is it disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The "Administrator" account disappeared.

The built-in Administrator account is disabled by default in Windows 8.0+ and Windows Server 2012+

> Is this normal behavior or did I do something wrong?

This is indeed normal.

> Can I get it back?

You just need to enable it again, the account still exists, the built-in Administrator account cannot be deleted.  Worth pointing out the name of the built-in Administrator user can be changed.

Comment: [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221)