# Unable to login into admin account in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, administrator, uac, password-recovery

I have Windows 7 utimate edition on my PC, After a long time i work on my PC i am not able to log into my "Administrator" account, when i check the "Administrators" localgroup i found it have two account with the name "Administrator" and "user".

Since "Administrator" account is disabled in Win 7, i try to activate it through command prompt in safe mode with standard user privilage i always got message 'System error 5 has occurred. Access denied'.

I tried to change "Standard User" to give permission of "Administrators" still the 'Access denied' message.

Whenever i try to change any thing on my PC, popup comes up to enter password of account "user". I forgot this account's password.

I do not have password recovery disk. I tried to boot my PC from USB still no success as "Standard User" can't change boot option.

Please help me, i searched and applied many online solutions still no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer).  Before you indicate this is not a duplicate, please read the accepted answer, because the instructions provided are indeed applicable to a Windows 7 installation.  The only difference is you would use a Windows 7 ISO instead of a Windows 10 ISO.  To reiterate the fact, being an Administrator, is not required to enable the built-in Administrator.

Comment: Also, you can try to change the user to admin without administrator account, you can refer to the following link, just see the solution 2. https://www.isunshare.com/blog/change-user-to-administrator-windows-10-without-admin-password/#solution2

Answer (score 0):

You first need to right clink on CMD and select run as administrator, that will deal with `'System error 5 has occurred. Access denied'`. `Running as admin` will not acctually run program with `Adminstartor` account, it will just give your account Administrator token (Microsoft made this very confusing). From `cmd` type `net user administrator /active:yes`. That will enable user `Administrator`. Then type `net user administrator *`. It will prompt you to change password for `Administrator` account. Type in new password twice. Now you need to log off from your current session and you will two accounts to choose for logging in. Choose `Administrator` account and do the necessary changes. With `Administrator` account you will be able to add/remove other accounts, change password, etc.

**Note** You should change password for Administartor account to more complex one after doing the changes. Also the best cause of action is to disable it all together.