# Admin account issue

Tags: windows-10, login, administrator, login-screen

I accidentally deleted the 2 admin account on my windows 10 then I restart my pc. After restart I'm not able to log in to my PC there's no account to be choose. What should I do?

Comment: Here is a [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer) to a post where this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Deniele, you still have the administrator account, it's just that it has been disabled and hidden from you.

So what you should do is boot into safe mode, enable the administrator account, log in as administrator, then create a user account for you to use. You could also run recovery software and recover all of your deleted information, that is an option.

But lets get you logged in first.

To get to safe mode start your PC and once it is up hold the SHIFT key and click on the POWER icon, select RESTART. You'll see a screen with 3 options come up. Select TROUBLESHOOT then select ADVANCED OPTIONS, then select STARTUP SETTINGS, then select RESTART.

The computer will restart and show you another menu, press the number 4 key to select SAFE MODE. The computer will enter safe mode and give you a desktop.

Now we want to enable the administrator account, to do this I want you to RIGHT-CLICK on the START button. A menu will appear and you will have to select either COMMAND PROMPT(ADMIN) or you may have to choose WINDOWS POWERSHELL(ADMIN), which ever one appears for you.

A window will open and now you should type

NET USER ADMINISTRATOR /ENABLE:YES

and then hit the ENTER key.
It should respond by saying 'The command completed successfully'.

You can now reboot and log in as 'administrator'.

This was setup when Windows was installed, so you will need to know what password was used at that time. If there was no password then it will boot up and go right into the administrator account.

Now as administrator, you can recreate your old account or run recovery software and recover the accounts you deleted. Good luck, hope this helps you out.

Comment: Hi Larryc! I cant do the first step because I'm not on my regular screen. I'm on the page after the restart and asking me to log in to my pc and there's no account to choose. Please help me

Comment: Hit escape and cancel out of any login. You should see the POWER icon. (a circle with a line through it) in the lower right side of the screen. Hold the SHIFT key and click on that icon, then select RESTART.