# How do I reset the Vista net user password when it does not work with the User Name "C&D Sign Company"?

Tags: windows-vista, passwords

Recently C&D Sign Company sold their business to a local church.  Now I have this machine in my shop, and all my efforts to reset the password, including Ophcrack, and many other methods, changing utilman.exe to cmd.exe are to no avail.

C&D Sign Company is the Administrator. Two other accounts are standard users.  The hidden Administrator account is not accessible because I don't have the password for C&D.

Net User error "The command completed with one or more errors. It has to be the user name, C&D Sign Company!

Trying this: net user   command ...
I entered net user C&D Sign Company none ...

Generated Report is as follows: 
account active - YES 
Account Expires - NEVER 
Password last set - 2/13/19 
Password expires 3/27/2019
Password changeable 2/13/19
Password required - YES 
The user may change password - YES
Workstations allowed - ALL 
Last Login - 2/1/3/19
Login Hours allowed - ALL 
Local Group Memberships *Users
Global Group memberships *None 
The command completed successfully.
'D' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.  (referring to C&D, I assume.)  There is an account on the machine with nothing in it, a standard account, non-admin labeled "C."

Please help me.  The Church has all the hardware to make the signs and needs the computer to program the equipment.  Thank You.

Comment: User Account Control window pop up shows C&D Sign Company and wants a password, all attempts return with Logon Failure: unknown user name or bad password.

Comment: You can enable the built-in Administrator without knowing the current Administrator password. All you need is a Vista installation disk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer).  While the linked duplicate is for Windows 10, the solution to the general problem of not having an accessible Administrator account, is exactly the same for Vista.

Comment: For some reason most password reset utilities do not work on Vista, the only one I have found that works reliably is ERD made by Microsoft, it is part of the DaRT package, you want ERD 6.0, not publicly available but can be found....https://superuser.com/a/247953/40928

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

Comment: I have had extremely good luck blanking passwords with [Offline NT Password & Registry Editor](https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/).

Answer (score 0):

I found a program called Offline NT Password and Registry Editor.  This little GEM did the trick, cleared the password, and got me back on track with the machine.