# Windows 10 Account locked out. How to unlock ? (I have a password reset disk but that did not help)

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, login

Account is locked out on Windows 10. There is no other account. I disabled Admin Account.

I went thru the motions of password reset disk (USB) thinking that would help, but it's no use. After I retype new password, confirm, click next.. it says "An error occurred".

It kind of makes sense as I know the password, I have not forgotten it, so I don't want to reset, I want to unlock the Account.

Is there a command line to unlock the account?

**EDIT**: My question was about unlocking my existing account, not enabling the default Admin account. 
Whether that other question/answer will actually work for my case, I don't have time right now to download ISO's and follow thru with the procedure to confirm such. Maybe next time, but for now I've gone with the Linux way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer)

Comment: If you don’t have time to download a Windows ISO, then why was the answer, that requires a Linux ISO accepted? How you unlock the account is to enable the default Administrator user, a password reset won’t by itself, unlock the account if it’s locked.  The duplicate question also doesn’t require an ISO, booting into the Advanced Startup, would also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a bootable linux media that has the chntpw command.

The chntpw linux command has the ability to unlock your account.  However,  I have never gotten the set password to work.  In fact, setting a password from this utility, for me, has always broken the password.  The only option I know works for certain is the **clear password** option.

Unlocking your account and clearing the password are 2 different menu options.

Once you login with no password you can change the password back from within windows.

Comment: yes ok. i've done the linux option in the past to reset the SAM but was hoping there is a Windows cmd line option. So far i found NET USER but it does not respond well !

Comment: The question is the NET USER command requires that you be logged in the machine with admin privileges.  If your account is locked, how are you logging in?  Are you booting off of some kind of CD/DVD/ or USB?

Comment: I restarted to the troubleshoot option.. (Hold down Shift while restart). It gave me option to go into cmd prompt. When cmd prompt came up, i actually could log in using the locked out account (thats how far i got)

Comment: At the command prompt what happens if you type compmgmt.msc

Comment: compmgmt.msc is not recognized as an internal or external cmd; the prompt says X:\windows\system32> which is strange because i have a C:\ not an X:\

Comment: change to the C: drive, and verify it has the windows folder, or find the drive with the windows folder on it that is NOT x:  try C:\Windows\System32\compmgmt.msc  Changing C: to whatever drive you find windows on.

Comment: i found the cmd compmgmt.msc but when i run it.. a dialog box pops up with "No such interface supported".. when i Ok it on the cmd line it says "Access is denied." (because it appears i need elevation..too bad.. cant elevate myself with sudo)

Comment: Get a bootable linux media with chntpw and clear the password.  Then you won't have to keep struggling on in this mode.