# Windows 10 Boot Loop after Automatic Update - Password not accepted

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 Boot Loop after Automatic Update - Password not accepted

Woke this morning to my laptop in some sort of recovery mode after a Automatic Windows Update. Most of the options I'm interested in (Command Prompt, Safe Mode, etc) require authentication.

My account is the only one that appears. I select it, but my password isn't accepted. The password prompt shows my Microsoft Live email address and so I am assuming the password being requested is for the Live account - and I definitely know what that password is, but it I keep being told the password is not correct.

I have Grub installed which allows me to boot either Ubuntu or Windows 10 Professional (Default). I'm able to boot Ubuntu as expected.

I had been using a PIN to log into Windows ... The Windows 10 boot goes directly to recovery mode where I seem to be DOA because the password is needed.

Is there any way to recover Windows local password or somehow get into my account again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer)

Comment: Once you have enabled the built-in Administrator account you can use that, to resolve the problem with your existing account, and then proceed to troubleshoot the reason your system booted into a recovery environment,