# Taking back control of Windows 8 Machine: Exhausted Options

Tags: windows-8, passwords, user-accounts, troubleshooting

I have a Dell Windows 8.1 with lost administrative accounts' passwords. I have exhausted the following options:

- chntpw: I have tried both booting chntpw and a live CD boot to install and run chntpw. I enable and blank password for the built-in administrator account and also blank the password for the regular administrator account. Upon reboot, I notice no changes. Strangely, chntpw claims that the password is "already blank" when booting chntpw from USB stick. NOTE: I have used chntpw several times in the past on Windows 7 and older OSs. This is, however, the first time I have used it on 8.1.
- Ophcrack: I am not familiar with this software, so I might have been using it wrong. The software seemed to not even be able to recognize that the accounts had passwords.
- Perhaps there is no local password, but rather a Microsoft account password? There seems to be no indication of this. The option on the sign-on screen to "reset password" mentions no Microsoft account, only to insert a recovery USB stick.
- Trinity Rescue Kit: I could not figure it out. I kept running into issues I couldn't find support for online. I'd rather not go that route.
- Reset to factory settings: No luck. There is no recovery partition (no option to "reset this PC" from login or from troubleshooting boot screen). Creating a recovery ISO requires an admin password. I tried to create a recovery ISO from Dell's website, but they do not have any images for this device.

At this point, I do not know what to do. The only option left I can think to do is to buy a new Window's license and install, but I naturally do not want to go that route. Fellow technicians, are there any options I have not attempted? What else can I do from the options I have tried? At this point, any destruction of data is fine, save for Windows itself, which I would like to keep!

As described in my question, I have tried the solutions listed in the similar question.

Comment: Why would you purchase a new Windows 8.1 license?  [You can simply reinstall Windows 8.1 for free.](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/1046062#1046062)  Although reinstalling Windows, due to the fact you cannot remember your password, isn't a real solution to the problem.  [This can be solved by enabling the built-in Administrator account.](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221).

Comment: This problem can be solved for free, do not spend money, to solve this problem.

Comment: FWIW Any Dell OS install disc should detect license automagically

Comment: @ivanivan, the Dell recovery ISO creator requires admin permissions to run, so I need to run it on a different device and enter in the Dell serial number. This is where I get the error of "no images for this device"

Comment: See solutions here....https://superuser.com/a/247953/40928

Comment: @Moab, No to the duplicate, I have tried the solutions (as described in question) on that question. They are not working.

Comment: @Reubens4Dinner I believe that you can actually order a CD/DVD from Dell.  I'll whip up an answer with this info, since it is too long to be a comment with the URLs etc.

Comment: I don't see how the [sethc.exe method](https://superuser.com/a/247953/8672) in the link by @Moab can fail.

Answer (score 1):

If simply reinstalling Windows will work for you, you can download a Dell installation disk that will read the activation/license from the BIOS, etc.

Doing this from a Windows machine will force you through their download/create process.  However, you can use the non-Windows users version.

From https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln299044/how-to-download-and-use-the-dell-os-recovery-image-in-microsoft-windows?lang=en

To manually download the Windows or Linux ISO file on a non-Windows PC:

- Browse to Dell Recovery Image website from a non-Windows PC.
- Enter the Service Tag of the Dell PC and verification code, and click
  Check Availability.
- Select the Windows or Linux operating system and click Download
  Selected Files.
- Review and agree to the Terms and Conditions, click Continue for the
  download to begin.
- Save the Dell ISO recovery image file on your PC.

Burn to disk or xfer to USB in your "normal" way.   Note that if the sticker on your computer is worn/torn/missing for the service tag you can find it in the BIOS.

Comment: Dell's website did not find a recovery for this device's service tag.