# Does using the reset option in windows 10 remove all user accounts?

Tags: windows-10

A client forgot his wondows 10 password and doesn't mind loosing his files. I was wondering if using the reset this PC option and choosing to remove all files will remove all user accounts. I have never used this option before and a complete format would waste a lot of time.

Comment: Reset will reinstall Windows 10, if you choose to keep nothing, all files from the old Windows installation will be transfered to the `Windows.old` folder.  The user profile will be transfered, so the user would still need to know, the password to that profile.  Use the built-in Administrator to reset the password to the account in question, if it's currently disabled, you should enable it.  I am choosing to flag this as a duplicate, due to the fact, the proper solution to this problem is to use the built-in Administrator.  What Reset does exactly would be a different duplicate though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I used the option... It completely wiped the system clean and I had to create a completely new user account, passwords and find all drivers from scratch.  Nothing from the old OS was left.

Comment: You could have reset his Windows password in about 10 minutes, using a bootable DVD. Blowing everything away was a terrible way to handle a forgotten password. Talk about throwing the baby out with the bathwater. This was an "XY problem". The real issue was resetting his password.

Comment: I have no idea how I could have done that. If you could point me in the right direction so that I could investigate and hopefully not have to got the long next time

Comment: Absolutely. I'll post an answer for you now.

Answer (score 1):

This was a perfect example of an XY problem.

You asked how to remove all Windows user accounts, when really, all you were trying to do was allow a user to use their PC again after they forgot their password.

So the real question here was simply, "How can I reset a user's password in Windows 10?"

It's actually very straightforward:

1. Download [ophcrack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/)
2. Create a bootable ophcrack optical disc or USB drive
3. Reboot the target PC and select the bootable media as the boot drive
4. Use ophcrack to perform an offline attack (i.e. outside of Windows) and reset the user's password stored in the SAM file
5. Reboot and confirm the user is now able to log in to his account using his new password

Once you have the disc created, the actual password reset procedure only takes around five minutes.

[image]

Comment: This seems like overkill.  Wouldn’t enabling the built-in Administrator account be easier? Which is what I suggested back on August 7th.

Comment: @Ramhound if the guy can't log in to Windows at all, how can he enable the built-in admin account in the first place?

Comment: @wrecesham - Read my answer to the duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> brings up run box then type `netplwiz` when it pops up uncheck users must enter password when signing in and you will be able to access the desktop and update whatever info I know it's a few years after this posting but I had a similar issue this option worked in less then 7 mins, I figured I'd share in case someone else runs into the same problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).