# can I log into a Dell R710 server running Windows 2016 Server Evaluation Edition?

Tags: windows

I am building a homelab to get some experience with routers, switches and Windows Server. I just purchased and was delivered yesterday a Dell R710 server. It has included Windows 2016 Server Evaluation Edition. I want to upgrade memory, drives and maybe the iDrac. However I unboxed it yesterday and can't log into the OS. Is there a way to reset the password or is there a generic way to log in? I am new so not much experience. I don't have a disk or a iso. copy on USB drive by the way. I have my CCNA in Routing & Switching but no Server experience. Hoping a helping hand....thanks. Stanley

Comment: Have you tried to enable the built-in Administrator account in order to reset the password to the account you are trying to access?

Comment: As stated I'm totally new so can you sketch it out?

Comment: [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221).  You will indeed need an ISO of Windows Server 2016.  **I cannot help you with that step.**

Answer (score -2):

If the account you are trying to login is already Administrator and there are no other accounts available you could attempt a reset via chntpw.

You’re going to need Linux Live CD (eg. SystemRescueCd)

- Boot the Linux CD
- Once you’re in the terminal. You need to mount the Windows partition. Before you can do that, you need to know what the device path is. Use the `fdisk -l` command to list the available hard drives and partitions. The Windows partition is usually /dev/sda1 or /dev/sda2` but could be different on your system.
- Create a mount point, and mount the Windows partition, and then navigate to the config directory. Note that the casing on the Windows and System32 directories may be different on some systems. Typing the cd command as I have below should work 99% of the time.
- `mkdir /mnt/windows`
- `ntfs-3g /dev/sda2 /mnt/windows`
- `ls -l /mnt/windows` (if the files are not those of disk "C:\" you need to umount it with `umount /mnt/windows` and mount another partition)
- `cd /mnt/windows/[Ww]indows/[Ss]ystem32/config`

chntpw works by modifying the SAM, SYSTEM, and SECURITY hives (i.e. files). I recommend you backup these files first. Note that the filenames are case-sensitive, so you may need to use the `ls` command to verify the casing.

- `cp SAM SAM.bak`
- `cp SYSTEM SYSTEM.bak`
- `cp SECURITY SECURITY.bak`

Use chntpw -l to list the available users. This is an important step, because when working with chntpw, the usernames are case-sensitive. Each time you call the chntpw command, you need to tell it the name of the SAM, SYSTEM, and SECURITY hives.

- `chntpw -l SAM SYSTEM SECURITY`

Reset the password for the user by running the command below. You’ll be presented a User Edit Menu that includes options to clear the password, change the password, promote the user to an admin, and unlock & enable the account.

- `chntpw -u USERNAME SAM SYSTEM SECURITY`

I personally, recommend you use the 1 - Clear (blank) user password option.

You’ll then be given the prompt Write hive files? (y/n) [n]:. Type y and hit Enter or your work will be in vain.

- `cd ; umount /mnt/windows`
- `Reboot` (eject cd)

At this point the Administrator user should login with no password

If something goes wrong (eg. infinite reboot) it is sufficient to restore the .bak files.

Comment: Well Hell....it looks like I'll be going to the Linux study guides. Thanks for the educational summary. I'm out of my league but in a month I'll be back in. Thank you for the shellack!

Comment: It looks like I'm going to have to find a copy of Windows Server 2016 and just re-install it to get going. I feel some of the people on this site look down on the newbie and don't remember when they were one.

Comment: did you try chntpw? it did not work? anyway, I understand you.. they took me 4 points for suggesting you this method ..

Comment: I did not try chntpw because I'm not Linux savvy. Yet. As I stated before I am totally new and just finished with Cisco entry level cert. I did get a Linux book though and have started my studies. Thank you for your reply and I'm sorry they took points from you. You don't deserve that.