# Windows asks for "administrator permission" to install update

Tags: windows-update, administrator

Windows update has downloaded an important update. However, when trying to install it, Windows says "You need to provide administrator permission: to complete this task, you need to sign in with an administrator account or ask an administrator to complete the task for you".

Since this is my personal PC I have administrator rights. Ok, not by default, but I can always right-click a file and "run as admin". In here, however, there is no such thing. Right-click does nothing. So how can I run this as admin?

Comment: Is the account you're using apart of the `Administrators` group?  If not, you will need to launch Windows Update manually via Run (Hold **`CTRL` + `SHIFT`** when clicking _Ok_) or an admin terminal, issuing **>=Win10:** `explorer ms-settings:windowsupdate` || **<Win10:** `wuauclt.exe /updatenow`.  Depending what your answer is to the first question, I'll add this as an answer.

Comment: You will have to log into an Administrator account in order to solve this problem.  You can use the built-in Administrator account.  [If it's disabled for some reason, the process to enable it is extremely easy.](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221)