# Unable to login in to windows because account was desactivated

Tags: windows, windows-10

I was previously in a company that were using the Office365 suite. 1 year ago I got a brand new computer and I installed windows on it. The thing is that I used my old company's credentials to log into that new windows account.

I recently left the company and they desactivated my account. So right now i'm not able to login into my windows account anyone since I was using the same email/password to login

Is there a way to recover that and change the email ?

Thanks

Comment: Activate the built-in [Administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221) account and create a new account.  If you are unable to log into the account there isn't a way to my knowledge to disconnect the local account from it.  Which is the reason I suggest just creating a new user profile

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine if you or the company owns Windows. If they own, you need to purchase a new license. If you own it, log into Microsoft, access your account and change the password.

Same for Office 365. You can log into your Office Account and change the password. You must have your own Office license to do this.

However, and most important, you must have your own licenses. You cannot keep the company software (Windows or Office) because you are not with the Company any more.

Comment: If he had a company login ("they disabled his account") then he will not be able to get to Office.