# Device Manager Windows 10 20H2 says "you are logged in as a standard user" but I am admin and domain admin

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-domain

Domain joined PC where I am both admin at the PC and the Domain Admin and on my PC Device Manger says "you are logged in as a standard user".

Also merging .reg files to change back stuff that Win 10 updates set to defaults (non-critical, almost all cosmetic) results with error that some items not updated because of insufficient rights.

As both a local admin and domain admin, why?

Tried rejoining PC to domain. Nope. Server is 2012r2 and fully updated.

[image]

So what the...?  Anyone seen this and found a fix?

And also this:

[image]

Comment: @Ramhound
So an opinion that is shared by millions that Windows updates break stuff all the time and are broken almost all the time before they fix it later on you refuse to help.

How is this other than a fanboy MS person (or MS employee) ?  Their updates are broken ALL THE TIME, and that is a fact that even a 10th grader can determine with a basic Google or even Bing Search.

Sorry you are offended by that, it really does mean that you should not pretend to help and just say "I will help only if you kiss MS butt"

Comment: Rs this [link text]( https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221) that won't work precisely because of what I described.

Comment: I don’t appreciate you putting words into my mouth.

Comment: Enabling the built-in Administrator account works as expected. No need to do anything more than enable via Powershell.  IT can access all admin tools with no warning/disablement. 

Any other domain user accounts that have Admin permissions do not work on this specific PC  - as per the screen caps.  Removing PC from Domain and re-joining does not help.  

If I make a shortcut to, say, device manager, and run-as-admin, then it recognizes I am an admin: no prompt to sign in and UAC is set to 0.  This was not the case before having to upgrade 20H2.

So - anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

This may be blunt force but this is fixed by disabling UAC:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
```

"EnableLUA"=dword:00000000

Of course this has never been the case - all was well on this PC under Win 10 1909.  Upgraded itself to 20H2 and problems began.  No idea why but finally I can actually use Device Manager, and the rest of the panels etc. to actually, you know, manage my own PC.