# How to log into a hidden account after it has been created in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, user-accounts

Here is the situation:

A Windows 10 (build 19041) installation has the following active local accounts:

1. `Teenager` account ( without administrative privileges )
2. `Daddy` account ( a member of the local `Administrators` group )

The `Teenager` username appears on the Logon screen but the password to this account is NOT known (it has been changed and forgotten). Kids...

The password to the `Daddy` account is known, but the `Daddy` account does not appear on the Logon screen because it has been hidden with:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList\"Daddy"=dword:00000000
```

Note, that the `Daddy` account is only hidden and it is not disabled (it is active) and in the past it was being used with the `RunAs` command successfully executed in the context of the `Teenager` account.

Also, Windows 10 does NOT prompt for the user name on the Logon screen because that policy is disabled by:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\"dontdisplaylastusername"=dword:00000001
```

See this blog post: “[How to make Windows 10 ask for user name and password during log on](https://winaero.com/how-to-make-windows-10-ask-for-user-name-and-password-during-log-on/)”

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> multiple times on the Logon screen does not bring up the prompt for a different user name, like it did in previous versions of Windows, because Microsoft has disabled that behavior in their infinite stupidity and spite.

So how to log into the `Daddy` account? Would Safe Mode help?

Comment: I would try Safe Mode. Windows 10 does not hide logins normally.  Is there a right arrow attached to the login line? There might be.

Comment: Enable the built/-In Administration account and unhide your existing account do you can change the password of the other account.  See my existing answers on how to do that

Comment: @Ramhound: Your tutorial on enabling the built-in Administrator account listed here:  https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer assumes that the computer can be booted from a CD, DVD or USB drive into WinRE. In this case, that assumption is false due to the lack of BIOS/UEFI access to change the boot drive. However if it is possible to edit Windows Registry (or hive) from the Safe Mode with the knowledge of the password to the ACTIVE `Daddy` account with administrative privileges, then the problem is solved. Is it?

Comment: @John. No right arrow exists on the login screen.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson - You never mentioned not having access to your firmware settings.  Are you asking me if your own problem is solved?

Comment: @Ramound: The BIOS password is on the SSD.  I did not mention that the SSD is soldered to the motherboard either ...and a dozen of other hardware difficulties. I asked how to log into an active hidden account - not into an inactive (disabled) account. My mention of the Safe Mode was in the context of editing the Windows Registry (or a lone hive), because the active (but hidden) administrative account can be accessed after editing the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\"dontdisplaylastusername"`. So is it possible to log into Safe Mode as `Daddy` or not?