# Please Help!!! Forgotten Windows 8.1 Administrator login password on HP 110-210 Desktop PC

Tags: windows-8, passwords, login, administrator

I have reviewed the existing "fixes" or ways to restore and/or recover or remove administrator passwords on Windows 8.1 operating systems on other sites to no avail.  I'm hoping someone in this community can help.  I inherited a somewhat antiquated but functional HP 110-210 AMD A4-5000 64-bit PC running Windows 8.1 from a deceased friend.  Unfortunately, and as is common, he left no record of his passwords.  Also, I have no restore disk or Windows installation disk.  I just need a way to bypass, change or retrieve his Administrator password.  It seems he created a User by using the existing system Administrator account, if that makes sense.  I see no Admin account; just his name which has Admin access.
I would like to avoid doing a restore if possible due to the aforementioned lack of OS installation software.  I am pretty well versed in computer science and command line/Windows usage.  However I am leery of many of the posts I have seen due to possible outdated software or hacks that may damage my OS.  I do have access to another PC but it runs Win10.  I am struggling to get a business off the ground and this PC would handle the applications needed to automate and simplify much of the day to day stuff.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.   Best wishes for 2021 to the community!  Sincerely, nomadsxdx

Comment: Use Pogo Stick:  https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/   Make a bootable USB Key with Rufus.  Start with it and you can reset the Admin Password.

Comment: Enable the built-in Administrator account.  [You will need a Windows 8.1 ISO in order to accomplish that task](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221).  You can use the Windows 8.1 [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8ISO) to download a Windows 8.1 ISO

Comment: Here is a similar thread discussed before, please kindly check if it was helpful to you: [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)