# How to reset Windows 10 password from the installation DVD?

Tags: windows-10, password-recovery

I haven't used my computer in a while and I forgot the Win 10 password. It only has one user.

I understand there are many utilities but before trying them I would like to know if it's possible to reset the Windows 10 password from the installation DVD.

I started it and chosed repair instead of install, I get various options but I can't find any option for resetting the password

Reset or retrieve the password but I think retrieving is not an option.

Also I tried from the login screen to reset password but it requires internet and it does not have internet

Comment: Can you get temporary Internet? Likely it was set up with a Microsoft Account and you need to log into Microsoft Live to change the Microsoft Account password.

Comment: Likely a hard duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221) question

Comment: “I understand there are many utilities but before trying them I would like to know if it's possible to reset the Windows 10 password from the installation DVD.” - You don’t; You use an Administrator account and reset the password from within Windows