# my windows login is connected to a deleted google account that can't be restored; what do i do?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, login, gmail

The username for my login is a gmail account that existed before I was thirteen, and before Google decided to say "no kid under 13 can have their own account." I was turning 13 in literally two weeks. We contacted Google Support and tried everything, but we were unable to restore the account.

Then, years and years later, I found my old laptop that I had forgotten about. It just so happened that the username was that exact gmail account. Of course, it denies login, saying "We can't sign into your account."

What am I supposed to do? I never made an admin account on it, and it doesn't give me any options to make a new account. Am I missing something?

Is it possible to fix/reset this, or do I have to install windows again?

Note: Since I'm unable to log in, I have no idea what version of Windows it is.

Comment: Enable the built-in account.  That will allow you to create a new account on the device.  The account would be a Microsoft Account anyway which isn’t existence isn’t connected to the Google Account

Comment: @Ramhound how do i do that? is that easily answerable on google, or should i look in superuser?

Comment: [It is indeed documented](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221)

Comment: @Ramhound im a complete noob at computers outside of using a linux terminal on my pc (not this laptop in question), so how do i do this: "This tutorial assumes you know how to create an installation disk, boot to that disk, and enter WinRE which is contained on that disk."

Comment: Yes; Creating an installation disk is well documented.  Download the Media Creation Tool and run it and follow the onscreen prompts.  Outside of that, if you want an answer, you will have to provide more specifics about the installation (like for instance what version of Windows you are using).

Comment: hmm ok will try. thanks!