# I can no longer log in my windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, cmd.exe, msconfig

I needed to uninstall printer driver and i couldn't do so because it was in use. I saw article online to open msconfig and change from normal boot to diagnose mode. So i did that after restarting i am greeted with this error.
[image]

Clicking setup my pin doesn't really do anything.

I tried to open msconfig from recovery comand prompt but no luck.
[image]

So i am stuck here. How can i revert the settings back to normal mode. I tried safe boot as well same problem there as well. I don't have a system restore point as well. The only solution i see is to reinstall windows.

Is there any way to revert the changes i made or open msconfig from recovery mode CMD?

Comment: You will have to enable the [built-in Administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221) and configure your machine to boot normally.  You are unable to log into the local account attached to your Microsoft Account since the background service responsible was disabled when you enabled Diagnostic Startup.

Comment: Can you provide a link for a guide or step by step instructions to do so? @Ramhound

Comment: you misspelled msconfig in your screenshot

Comment: @Skyyy - I did provide a guide to solve the problem. If you need help to create a Windows 10 installation media, there are existing guides, you can use to accomplish that task.  Generally speaking, if you already have a command prompt, you can just start from step 2 at that point.  You are basically looking to enable the built-in Administrator by modifying `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\REM_SAM\SAM\Domains\Accounts\Users\000001F4` which by default is disabled and not enabled.

Comment: @Ramhoud i followed the instructions and enabled administrator account. But after restart i don't see any another account just mine only.

Comment: @Yorik mybad i tried `Start msconfig` no luck same error

Comment: What’s results if you type: `where msconfig.exe`, `echo=%path%` and `echo=%pathext%`

Comment: Unfortunately, I have reset my pc to gain access.