# How to unlock Windows device from Microsoft account?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft

I have an Acer Nitro 5, Windows 10, the only account I have is my Microsoft account.

I know both my Microsoft and Windows password.
I can still log in to Microsoft, but not to my Windows computer,
because I just lost my computer, so I locked it online from my Microsoft account and displayed a message to the person who would find it to get it back to me.

Luckily someone returned it. But now when I try to turn on my computer
and enter the right password, it says

> You can't login to this account because an admin has locked it,
> turn on WiFi and ask admin to connect first.

Since in my Windows the only account I have is Microsoft account, I can't login to it anymore.

I tried to open other Windows from USB and make a CMD on the start menu, then I created an other account, but all of them are locked now.

Comment: Enable the built-in Administrator then use that account to unlock your normal account

Comment: Try this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/administrator-unable-to-unlock-a-locked-computer-336fe704-ebab-35ee-c5ce-be8a58045982) Method 1.

Answer (score 2):

> I know both my Microsoft and Windows password. I can still log in to Microsoft, but not to my Windows computer because I just lost my computer, so I locked it online from my Microsoft account and displayed a message to the person who would find it to get it back to me.
>
> Since in my Windows the only account I have is a Microsoft account, I can't log in to it anymore.

1. [Enable the built-in Administrator account](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221)
2. Run `lusrmgr.msc`: 
    [image: Screenshot1]
3. View the properties of the user account you want to unlock
4. Unlock the account: 
    [image: Screenshot2]
5. Be sure to disable the built-in Administrator account when you are done

Answer (score 0):

the solution I tried and worked is

1. restore windows to few days ago, and done.
2. log in as you used to do