# Windows 10, User locked with unknown PIN and broken online account

Tags: windows-10, login

I have a very special problem:

A friend of mine gave me a Windows 10 laptop to fix. The issue:
Windows 10 wants a PIN number to login, but the laptop owner is not aware of a PIN. All we have is a password.

The login registered with this windows 10 seems to be an windows online account. Windows provides the method to send a code to the user's email address to be able to login, but here come the next problem:

The login name is an email address like "my.name@yahoo.de". So, Windows tries to send the code to access the laptop to that email address. But I cannot login to yahoo with "my.name@yahoo.de", but with "my.name@yahoo.com"  (different TLD)

I tried to login on another machine to this windows account via browser. But there I get a similar issue: New and unknown device, system will send a code to my registered email-address to verify the user... which is somehow "@yahoo.de" instead of "@yahoo.com".

A programmer would name this "dead-lock" ...

I guess I need to find a way to tell the microsot account that the login-name is still "my.name@yahoo.de", but send any emails regarding this login to "my.name@yahoo.com".

I cannot just rename the login-name from @yahoo.de to @yahoo.com, because I cannot tell the laptop with it's windows 10 about the user name change.

As a last solution I only have one idea: Unscrew the harddisk and make an external backup of all the data (hoping that data is not encrypted) and re-install the whole machine.

Would be great if anyone has an idea for another solution...

[update]
There is only one login account available and there is no option to select another account. I have right now no possibility to get access to the machine. I'm locked out completly. If you know any way of accessing the system in admin mode or similar, let me know.

Comment: Does the password belongs to a local account? If yes, login with the local account.

Comment: Enable the built-in Administrator account and create a new local user account.  The existing local account connected to the Microsoft account that is otherwise inaccessible will remain inaccessible.  You can separately connect Microsoft to regain access to the Microsoft account in order to eventually access the other linked local account.

Comment: @Reddy no, only this login, no option to change account or use a local one. So I assume there's just this one account.

Comment: @Ramhound How can I enable the built-in admin account? When I turn on the laptop, I only have one option: Login with this single user with a pin. That's it.

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221) are instructions to enable the built-in Administrator account.  Why don't you just reinstall Windows instead of using a local account linked to a Microsoft Account that isn't even yours?  If your not willing to reinstall Windows, enable the built-in Administrator account, and create a new local account that you actually know the password to.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the instructions. I was not aware that I can enable the account without loggin in to windows.

Reinstall takes time, especially because I don't know what software is installed and where to get the installation-medium to install it (the owner is about 70yrs old not really a techie ...)

Comment: You get the installation media from microsoft.com