# Reset windows 10 password

Tags: passwords, administrator, windows-restore

I recently restored my windows 10 because of virus. Now i see on lock screen "second user" and i can't log in. I also got no administrator password, so I can't use cmd to access `lusrmrg.exe` or anything like that. I tried to use my account but it says "password incorrect". Do I have to install windows again?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130828/discussion-on-question-by-aapo-pesonen-reset-windows-10-password).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

Answer (score 6):

There are various methods to reset your password. I have mentioned two of them here:

## 1. Using Hiren's Boot CD PE Windows 10

**If you already have a bootable media of any os, skip to method 2.**

- Download Hiren's Boot CD PE ISO from [here](https://hirensbootcd.org/download).
- Download Hiren's Boot CD PE ISO Burner from [here](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/files/ISO2USB.exe).
- Burn the ISO into a flash drive/ DVD drive/ or whatever you want using the tool, instructions are [here](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/burning/).
- Now insert USB into PC, shutdown it.
- Now boot your pc, press key F12/F11/DEL/INSERT/depending on your PC.
- Select the media of Hiren's Boot CD PE.
- Wait until it boots.
- After it boot, Click on Start Menu
- Click on All Programs
- Click on Security Folder.
- Click on Password/Password Recovery folder.
- Click on Lazesoft Password Recovery
- Click Next.
- Now click on "Administrator" account.
- Click Next.
- Click Reset/Unlock.
- Wait until it shows success then shutdown.
- Remove the Media and turn it on again.
- Log in to Administrator account, no password should be required.
- Click Win+R to open Run, then type "cmd".
- Type the following:
  `net user YourUsername ""`
  Make sure to replace YourUsername.
- Now type: `net user Administrator *` and set a password for Administrator
- Now Log out from Administrator and login to your account.
- Now change your password.

**Optional:**
Assign another administrator. Disable Windows built-in administrator by `net user administrator /active:no`

## 2. Using Other OS bootable media

**This is helpful if you already have a bootable media.**

### Windows Bootable

- Boot your pc from it.
- When it boots, Press SHIFT+F10 to open Command Prompt
- Now execute the following:

```
ren C:\Windows\System32\sethc.exe C:\Windows\System32\sethc.exe.BACKUP
copy C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe C:\Windows\System32\sethc.exe
ren D:\Windows\System32\sethc.exe D:\Windows\System32\sethc.exe.BACKUP
copy D:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe D:\Windows\System32\sethc.exe
```

**Repeat the same for E: and F: is available**

- Now shutdown your PC.
- Remove the media and boot again.
- On login screen, Press SHIFT key 5 times.
- When Command Prompt opens, type: `net user YourUserName *`. Make sure to replace YourUserName.

**Optional**: Assign another administrator. Restore sethc from BACKUP.

### Linux Bootable

**It might not work on all RedHat and SUSE based linux but still works on fedora.**

- Live boot your pc.
- Open a File Manager.
- Go to Windows Disk\Windows\System32
- Rename sethc.exe into sethc.exe.BACKUP
- Copy cmd.exe and rename it into sethc.exe
- Now shutdown your PC.
- Remove the media and boot again.
- On login screen, Press SHIFT key 5 times.
- When Command Prompt opens, type: `net user YourUserName *`. Make sure to replace YourUserName.

**Optional**: Assign another administrator. Restore sethc from BACKUP.

## At last

Which worked for you?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Very worthy answer +1.

Comment: Thx, 2-Windows worked for me.

Comment: Can also use Utilman.exe.  Then, on the logon screen click the accessibility icon and a command prompt will appear.