# How does resetting Windows passwords without authentication work

Tags: windows, security, passwords, hiren

I've come across this tool "Hiren" , and it allows me to enable the builtin Administrator, as well as change passwords of local users just by booting up the USB stick with its ISO. I couldn't find any explanation on why or how this works. Isn't this a gaping security hole for Windows? Apparently this is super easy and you don't even need a third party tool to achieve this. So, could anyone explain to me how exactly that process works, and if there is any protection against this (maybe encryption / Bitlocker? ).

EDIT: I don't mean, *how do I use Hiren*, but rather *how does Hiren work*. I want to understand the technology behind it, so to speak.

Comment: You need to start Hirens from a bootable USB and that is what Secure Boot is about.  That will stop Hirens.

Comment: [Step 1. Enable the built-in Administrator tool using a Windows 10 ISO.](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221)  Step 2. Login into the built-in Administrator tool and reset the account you are locked out of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer)

Answer (score 1):

> I couldn't find any explanation on why or how this works.

The OS has a file which contains a list of all user accounts, together with their password hashes. Editing the file to change the password hash to some known value (e.g. the hash of nothing) will result in the OS expecting that new password.

In Windows, that file is `SAM` (part of the Registry). Linux has `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`.

> Isn't this a gaping security hole for Windows?

No, it is generally not considered a security hole in any OS. The account system is meant to do its job *while the OS is running* – if it's not running, then its rules no longer apply; you could as well use Hiren to copy all the files out (bypassing the ACLs aka "file permissions" that the main OS would enforce), or to swap one .exe with another (making Minesweeper.exe steal all your files). Really, instead of booting Hiren, you could just take the system disk out, connect it to another computer via USB, and do the same thing.

In other words, if the attacker has physical access to the device (or just its system disk), then it's usually considered that *the attacker gaining physical access* was the real security hole.

Of course, with laptops and other mobile devices, security access is much easier to get, and the most commonly accepted solution is device encryption – having the entire system disk encrypted, e.g. through Windows BitLocker, would prevent someone from accessing any of the files inside. (Most modern CPUs have acceleration for encryption, so it doesn't make the system slower at all.)

(Disk encryption *should* be combined with Secure Boot to prevent e.g. tampering with the passphrase prompt, although realistically for most people it's more towards "may/should" than "absolute must".)

Though do keep in mind that the login password is also directly used to encrypt certain user-specific data. Resetting the password in this way (or really, in *any* other way, including if you had used legitimate Administrator powers to do so) will cause that user's EFS-encrypted files, or DPAPI-protected data like browser passwords (in *some* browsers), to become forever inaccessible. So if you're unable to use BitLocker, then EFS may help just a little bit.

> Apparently this is super easy and you don't even need a third party tool to achieve this.

Hiren *is* a third-party tool.

Comment: Thanks so much for that detailed answer! So, those password-encrypted user files are only being re-encrypted by the "legitimate" Windows password change process, but not with Hiren because Hiren (or any equivalent method) only changes this one hash entry, and nothing else. Would I gain access to those "lost" files again by changing the password to what it's previous value was? Since Windows doesn't salt passwords, it should result in the same hash

Comment: The NTLM hash is irrelevant – it is not used as input for deriving encryption keys (after all, the hash is as easy to _read_ from the SAM file as it is to overwrite). Instead the key is derived from the whole original password. Second, that key isn't used to decrypt files directly, but only the "DPAPI master key" (which then decrypts EFS certificate keypairs, and *those* decrypt files), and from what I know, if the DPAPI master key is found to be un-decryptable due to password mismatch, it'll get thrown away – making the stored private keys (EFS and others) impossible to regain access to.

Comment: That being said, you can back up _the EFS keypair specifically_ to a .pfx file through Certmgr.msc (recent Windows versions actually keep prompting you to make a backup of the EFS key as soon as you begin using EFS), then import the .pfx file anytime later (even on a different PC) and you'll become able to access the previously encrypted files. (Just make sure you export the private key and get a .pfx file, not a .crt file...)