# Forgotten Password Wizard stupidly hides itself repeatedly even when tried to bring it to focus with Alt+Tab keys

Tags: windows, windows-10, passwords, password-recovery, reset

As I mentioned in the Question title, I am trying to create a **Windows Password Reset Disk**(Logged in as Local Admin account as only one User account is there).

For the same, I am doing the first step i.e. search in Taskbar search: "Create a password reset disk", but when it opens a Forgotten Password Wizard it immediately hides itself and doesn't even come to focus when I once/repeatedly press Alt+Tab key pair.

I can see that Forgotten Password Wizard is open, but it never comes to focus even when USB pendrive is connected and detected.

Any suggestions for resolving this ??

Comment: [Why don’t you just enable the built-in Administrator account using a Windows 10 ISO?](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221)

Comment: Built-In Administrator is already enabled, but want to try out Forgotten Password Wizard and there doesn't seem any valid cause why that wizard would behave in this weird way...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it still exists, but sometimes the Forgotten Password Wizard will not open from the link in Control Panel/User Accounts/Create a Password Reset Disk or through Windows Search. Sometimes it will open in the background and is visible using Win+Tab. But you cannot bring it to the desktop. If this happens, close it with the X or through Task Manager (it will appear under rundll32). Now open CMD prompt and type: **RunDll32.exe keymgr.dll,PRShowSaveWizardExW**