# Wrong email registered on windows 11

Tags: microsoft-outlook, windows-11, verification

After fully reset windows 11 and insert an outlook account without verification (I didn't why, i wrongly input the email but somehow the email is valid, probably other people account)

So when the laptop boot, the windows asking me password of the email that I wrongly input.

Is there anyway I can escape this kind of situation or I just need to fully reset the laptop again?

Comment: Windows 11 just ask the email after that they don't ask for the password or verification stuff.

Comment: Enable the [built-in Administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221) account, create a new user, then link that to the correct Microsoft Account.  You can also use the Administrator account to perform another Reset.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway I can escape this kind of situation or I just need to
> fully reset the laptop again?

Since you have the wrong account and no password for it (and so cannot log in to the computer), the easiest way is simply to start again and reinstall (reset)  Windows.