# Windows 10 Upgrade Failed, Disk is now write protected, Cannot wipe system and install a new Windows or login normally

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, login, bitlocker, microsoft-surface

Surface Laptop 2 with BitLocker, cannot login normally

- Device : Surface Laptop 2
- OS : Windows 10 20H2 ( attempted upgrade
  to 21H1)
- Upgrade Fail cause: Battery died before updating fully
- Possible Repercussions : User Profile Corrupted , Windows Corruption or full Disk Corruption

A year ago I was tasked with fixing this Surface Laptop 2. I was told that it had powered down during an update and now you cannot login with your PIN.

I did my Diagnosis which you can find in the [OneNote](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkfcMN6-DbPknxzNle9odlF60mu_)

If you cannot access the OneDrive I'll write a TLDR:

1. Windows Hello face recognition is not working, neither is the correct password being registered
2. You cannot boot into safe mode by any of the methods listed by [MSFT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234#WindowsVersion=Windows_11)
3. I have tried every `diskpart`and then `attributes disk clear readonly`, `regedit` ( write protection DWORD 0,Storage Policies) and even tried `chkdisk`.
4. Tried `manage-bde` , `repair-bde` to remove the BitLocker encryption ( throws error device is write protected.
5. Tried wiping the drive with Hiren PE Boot CD and all of its tools
6. Tried using the admin cmd to make a user using : `net localgroup administrators User /add`
7. Tried booting into a live Windows 10 USB and getting into control panel and removing bde.
8. Recover boot options don't lead anywhere.
9. Cannot Install a new version of Windows ( write protected).
10. I have the *BitLocker Recovery key* but with that I am only able to read contents and copy them at a slow pace. *However this is of little use to me as the data is not relevant now and I just want my Laptop back*.

I have been on support calls with 5 different Microsoft engineers and
they couldn't give me a solution. I eventually close the case with
them but the laptop wasn't fixed

I have only one last resort to this problem : replace the physical SSD with a new one.

Can anyone help me getting back my laptop. Is there any chance to get it with the data too?

Comment: Are you able to enable the built-in Administrator account by using and booting to a 20H2. Enabling the built-in Administrator account does not require any permissions just the ability to boot into the WinPE.

Comment: Well I did try that but I cannot do anything on the cmd with it 
Also, If you're talking about if I can login into that built in admin , well no , I can't. :(

Comment: [Even if you boot to the WinPE contained on the installation disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221)

Comment: Well , I cannot do so with the WinRE , but I can try with the live installation or the HirenBoot CD PE. Will that do?

Comment: Why exactly can’t you boot to a Windows 10 ISO? My suggestion only works with the ISO.

Comment: I can boot into a windows 10 iso, but  I thought you meant windows RE, which comes preinstalled with a windows installation.

Comment: Try the suggestion of booting to the ISO, and using its internal capability, to load the registry hive and enable the built-in Administrator account

Comment: Sure, I'll do that

Comment: Hey @Ramhound, I did all the steps on 2 machines. ( one is the *Surface Laptop 2* : affected machine, other is my laptop : *Surface Laptop 3*.) 


I was able to activate the default admin in my unaffected device , but in the *Surface Laptop 2* ( the device for which I started the thread) I cannot see any *Administrator* account even after loading the SAM hive in C: drive