# I unhid the Administrator account on Windows 10. How do I re-disable it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, user-accounts, administrator

I unhid the administrator account on Windows 10 using the following commands, by booting into a recovery flash drive and using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

```
reg load HKLM\TEMP c:\windows\system32\config\sam
for /f "tokens=3" %a in ('reg query HKLM\TEMP\SAM\Domains\Account\Users\000001F4 /v F') do set str=%a
set str=%str:2000011=2000010%
reg add HKLM\TEMP\SAM\Domains\Account\Users\000001F4 /v F /t REG_BINARY /d %str% /f
reg unload HKLM\TEMP
```

How do I re-disable the Administrator account to where I can re-enable it in the future?

Comment: [Set the key to its original value](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221). The command set *2000011* to *2000010* in order to enable the account. To avoid issue user the user management GUI to disable the account. You can also follow the instructions in my answer and disable the account instead of enabling it. You can also just reverse the values in your command.

Answer (score 0):

Did you hide the default Administrator Account using the recovery flash drive?

Is there any other local admin account on the machine that is not hidden.

If so, then you can run command prompt as an admin:

1. Type `net user administrator /active:yes`
2. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Type `net user administrator "newpswd"` to reset the password.

After this you would be able to login to the hidden admin account

If you are just have a standard account and there are no local admins available as they were hidden then follow the steps mentioned by Ramhound to achieve the same.

Sorry my fault, I thought it was hid instead of unhide...

Here's the correct commands

Type net user administrator /active:no

Press Enter

If you want any other admin to be hidden then replace administrator with that admin username