# Unable to Windows 7 login password

Tags: windows, password-recovery

I have graduated this year and my laptop was linking with my College's Email. Now I couldn't remember the password or make reset because the College Email inaccessible to make reset steps. I have only one user and one drive (Drive C). My question, how reset password without losing data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer). Just replace Windows 10 ISO with a Windows 7 ISO

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use PogoStick to reset the Windows 7 Password without losing any data.

[Pogo Stick](https://pogostick.net/%7Epnh/ntpasswd/)

> Overview This is a utility to reset the password of any user that has
> a valid local account on your Windows system. Supports all Windows
> from NT3.5 to Win8.1, also 64 bit and also the Server versions (like
> 2003, 2008, 2012) You do not need to know the old password to set a
> new one. It works offline, that is, you have to shutdown your computer
> and boot off a CD or USB disk to do the password reset. Will detect
> and offer to unlock locked or disabled out user accounts! There is
> also a registry editor and other registry utilities that works under
> linux/unix, and can be used for other things than password editing.

Use RUFUS to make the required USB bootable USB Key