# Removed Computer from Domain; Only Possible Login is Domain User

Tags: domain

Lenovo ThinkCentre M715q running Windows 10

I removed a computer from our network domain and made it a workgroup. I thought I had enabled the administrator before restarting. The only login that comes up when rebooting the computer is the domain user. There is no option to switch to a local user or administrator. Using some of the questions here, I went into CMD to try and work around it, but nothing has helped. I deleted the domain user out of the registry and it still comes up when trying to log in.

What do I need to do to get back into the computer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer)

Comment: “What do I need to do to get back into the computer?” - If the machine has truly been removed from the AD domain.  Just enable the built-in Administrator account.

Comment: Yes - starting in safe mode I was able to get past it. Thank you.