# Administrator and power on password get wrongly entered and system disabled

Tags: administrator, system-restore

I have set my administrator and power on password. But today, my hp notebook pc's keyboard started malfunctioning. Because of which even after correctly entering password, my pc says "Invalid Password". After such three failed attempts, I get the message "System Disabled [ 62572479]". How can I remove this difficulty?  How can I enable my system?  If any member knows answer to my problem, may reply with correct problem solution

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221) question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer)

Answer (score 1):

The message "System Disabled [ 62572479]" is the standard BIOS response
to three failed passwords. The "62572479" is a seed number with which
an HP Support person can generate for you a valid password to unlock
the computer.

The next boot after you get this message will be a normal one,
and three following password errors will give again this message.

The website
[BIOS Password Recovery for Laptops](https://bios-pw.org/)
can do the same and supply you with a valid password from this seed,
just the same as HP Support.

However, better get your keyboard fixed, or add an external one,
for entering the password without error.