# Forgotten password for Windows 10 Intel ComputeStick

Tags: windows-10

My supervisor had an Intel ComputeStick with Windows 10 that he forgot the password for. I have looked at some other related questions, [such as this one](https://superuser.com/questions/951907/locked-out-of-windows-10-login-no-longer-shows-administrator-but-only-an-accou), however they require access to the command prompt and when I boot into safe mode the command prompt requires a password.

Is it a lost cause to try and get in, or should we just purchase a new one? Can the stick be factory reset somehow without the need for a password?

Thanks!

For reference, the ComputeStick model is #STK1AW32SC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Can the stick be factory reset?

> Reset the system to factory defaults:
>
> 1. Remove any SD card, if installed.
> 2. Press F8 when you see this prompt during boot: F8 to Activate Windows 8.1* Windows 10 * Recovery Mode.
> 3. Select Troubleshoot.
> 4. Select Reset your PC, then select Next.
> 5. Select Just remove my files.
> 6. Select Reset to start the restore process.

Source [Forgot password on New Intel compute stick M3](https://communities.intel.com/thread/107718)

Comment: Is it possible to take an image of the stick the rescue the files later? Never thought of this situation.

Comment: @sdkks No idea.