# I hid my only user account with administrator privileges (windows 7) Is there anyway I could fix this?

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, user-accounts, administrator

I had two user accounts, one which I usually used and one which I made a while ago. After turning on my computer today, only the second account is visible in the login screen, and I can't find a way to log into my main account. Only my main account had administrator privileges

What I think caused this problem is that I ran the following commands to fix my postgres install:

```
net user /add postgres <password>
net localgroup administrators postgres /add
runas /user:postgres cmd.exe
C:\Download\postgresql-9.1.4-1-windows.exe
```

Running `net localgroup administrators` shows the default 'Administrator' account, which I can't access because I didn't set a password, and the postgres account which I created, but not my old user account. The C:/Users folder for my main account still exists, but I can't access it because I don't have admin privileges. I remember the password I set on my postgres account and can run stuff with the `runas` command, but it seems like you can't get administrator privileges that way. The 'postgres' account isn't visible on the login screen.

My question is, is there anyway to regain access to my main user account?

Comment: Type `net user "name"` and see if it says if the account is active. If so Run something as admin like CMD by right clicking, and if you are not prompted for your user/password try Shift + Right click and Run as Different User.

Comment: See if this works for you>>>>>https://superuser.com/a/1154710/40928

Comment: In W7 you would boot into safe mode with command prompt, then do as suggested in the link.

Comment: Once the admin account is unhidden, log into that to unhide the other account.

Comment: Can't activate the administrator account without being logged into account with admin priviliges. I fixed my problem by booting into Linux and using chntpw.