# Locked out of Windows 10 and can't login because of BitLocker

Tags: windows, login, bitlocker, windows-domain

I quit a domain of my company. After rebooting my computer, it only shows the account for that domain, and I cannot login. I can't switch to administrator or other users.

I tried the method on [Locked out of Windows 10: login no longer shows Administrator, but only an account that I never used](https://superuser.com/questions/951907/locked-out-of-windows-10-login-no-longer-shows-administrator-but-only-an-accou?answertab=votes#tab-top). But my laptop was encrypted with BitLocker and I forget the recovery passwords and keys (also I can't retrieve any recovery keys for my Microsoft account). I can't access my drive at all.

I tried everything, but haven't had any luck. How can I login to my system with a local account? Thanks!

[image: login screen of my laptop]

Comment: I don't think you can. You've lost the key and you removed the only user account that had the key. I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: Have you contacted your company's IT department? I'm not entirely sure what you mean with 'quit my domain of my company', but perhaps they can help you regain access.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz @MiG Thanks for your replies. My laptop joined the domain of company before, I renamed my `Computer Name` and changed to `Members of WorkGroup`. Our IT department have no clue to solve the problem.

Comment: You should try extra hard to remember the bitlocker recovery password or find the key.

Comment: Without the recovery key the only solution is to format the drive and reinstall Windows

Answer (score 1):

If the Bitlocker Key is not safed in the Active Directory or you didn't make any backup of your key on an USB Stick, Network Share or other storage media you'll have a very hard time recovering your Computer.

Bitlocker is designed to prevent things like creating additional accounts or resetting someones password without access to an administrator account on your system.

Since no encryption or even TPM modules are 100% secure, there are detours to access data. There are [instructions](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/08/how-to-go-from-stolen-pc-to-network-intrusion-in-30-minutes/) on how to do this without soldering, but I recommend a new installation if the data is not absolutely necessary due to the high effort. (This only refers if your PC has an TPM Module which is used for bitlocker)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it, It seems a very hack way.